# Problemas para buscar los datos a través de la fecha

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con este código debido a que no me reconoce estas 2 variables y lo que necesito es convertirlas de String a Date, lo intentado de varias alternativas pero no me las reconoce y la idea es que me busque los datos en el formato a traves del formato mysql ya que tiene que buscarlas en Date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){


                var strFecha = '2017-01-04'; 
              //var strFecha = "<?php echo $_GET['desde'];?>";


                var idd = new Date();
                idd.setTime(Date.parse(strFecha));
                //el problema de la conversion esta cuando me sale cuando el programa me sale cuando hay un cruce en entre estas 2 variables idd y strFecha  
    strFecha = "2017-01-04"
    idd = Wed Jun 14 2017 18:12:58 GMT-0400 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)

                var dataLength = 0;
                var data = [];

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", {
                    title: {
                        text: "Graficos"
                    },
                    axisX: {
                        title: "HORA",
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        title: "Sensores",
                    },
                    data: [{type: "line", dataPoints: data}],
                });    

                //sensor="+ids+"&
                //"&hasta="+idh
                $.getJSON("graficoEntreFechas.php?fe=graficoBuscarSensor&desde="+idd, function (result) {
                    dataLength = result.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: new Date(result[i].FECHA),
                            y: parseInt(result[i].Cantidad)
                        });
                    }
                    ;
                    chart.render();
                });

            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <table border="1"> 
            <tr>                
                <th><a href="PaginaBuscarSensores.php">Listado por Sensor</a></th>                
                <th><a href="PaginaListadoEntreFechas.php">Listado Por Fechas</a></th>
                <th><a href="ListadoMensual.html">Listado Mensual</a></th>
                <th><a href="ExcelSensor.php">Exportar a Excel</a></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
        <br>

        <input type="button"  value="Mostrar" onclick="mostrar('bn')">
        <div id="bn" class="hidden">
            <div id="chart"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Y en que formato vienen las fechas? puedes poner un ejemplo del string  que devuelve la base de datos y especificar cual es el mes, dia y anyo?

Comment: las fechas vienen en formato Date. <?php

                
                $stm = $pdo->prepare("Select count(Equipo) as Cantidad, DATE(fecha) as fecha from Valores where '".$desde."'");
                $stm->execute();

el objetivo es que me reconozca la variable desde de mysql que esta en Date

nota: pensaba enviar la parte completa pero no me recibe mas caracteres

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer, si el problema es solo de javascript no incluyas codigo de php o mysql y trata de adaptar la pregunta lo mas objetiva posible. Si la pregunta no hay forma que se adapte solo a javascript, incluye los tags de php o mysql para que otros con conociemientos en estos temas te puedan ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas parsear las fechas en el cliente, eso debes hacerlo en el backend. Envía las fechas como string por [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) ya que estás consultando una API; no puedes enviar un objeto por URL.

```
.getJSON("graficoEntreFechas.php?fe=graficoBuscarSensor&desde="+strFecha, function (result) {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    data.push({
      x: new Date(result[i].FECHA),
      y: parseInt(result[i].Cantidad)
    });
  }
 chart.render();
});
```